# Get hive and hadoop version from within pyspark session

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I'm using pyspark upon a hadoop cluster with hive. I know its possible to get the spark, hive & hadoop versions from the command-line (`spark-submit --version`, `hive --version`, `hadoop version`) but how do I do the same from within pyspark?

getting the spark version is easy enough:

```
print("Spark version = ".format(spark._sc.version))
```

I can't figure out how to get the hive & hadoop version though. Anyone know? TIA

Answer (score -3, accepted):

ok, I solved it by doing this:

```
from sh import hive, hadoop
print("Hive version = {0}".format(hive("--version")))
print("Hadoop version = {0}".format(hadoop("version")))
```

Would be nice if there were a way to get it from the `spark` object without having to shell out. If anyone knows a way please let me know.

Comment: Good old SO. Getting marked down without explaining why, even though I actually solved my problem by doing this.

Answer (score 13):

Getting them from pyspark :

```
# spark
print(f"Spark version = {spark.version}")

# hadoop
print(f"Hadoop version = {sc._jvm.org.apache.hadoop.util.VersionInfo.getVersion()}")
```

Comment: ah nice, thanks. Hive not available in a similar way?

Comment: (still have to support py2 by the way hence no use of fstrings)

Comment: @jamiet I think there is no such config for Hive. But maybe you can try with SQL query via spark (after you enabled hive) like this: `spark.sql("select version();").show()`

Comment: print(f"Hadoop version = {spark._sc._jvm.org.apache.hadoop.util.VersionInfo.getVersion()}")

this one can also work for the hadoop version